# How do I use regex to add text in between a set of quotes?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to match a string in my configuration file.

```sh
/\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+''/gm
```

This regex matches the following field in my JavaScript file.

```js
  apiEndpoint: 
    '';
```

How do I extend this regex so that it inserts text `https://localhost:6000` between the set of single quotes?

```js
  apiEndpoint: 
    'https://localhost:6000';
```

Comment: If there can not be single quotes or spaces `\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+'[^\s']*'`

Answer (score 2):

Use this to *add*:

```
(\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+)''
```

Use this to *update* or *add*:

```
(\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+)'[^']*'
```

Replace with `$1'https://localhost:6000'`.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/NbRBp4/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    apiEndpoint:             'apiEndpoint:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ''                       '\'\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add matching between `'` using [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^`

```
\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+'[^\s']*'
```

The pattern matches:

- `\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `apiEndpoint:` a newline and 1+ whitespace chars
- `'` Match `'`
- `[^\s']*` match 0+ times any char except a whitspace char or `'`
- `'` Match closing `'`

» [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2qfy3/1)

Or if you want to allow whitespace chars and excaped `\'` in between:

```
\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
```

This pattern matches:

- `\s+apiEndpoint:\n\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `apiEndpoint:` a newline and 1+ whitespace chars
- `'` Match `'`
- `[^'\\]*` Match 0* times any char except `'` or `\`
- `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` Optionally repeat matching `\` followed by any char and again 0* times any char except `'` or `\`
- `'` Match `'`

» [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KANhH4/1) | [Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs%2BapiEndpoint%3A%5Cn%5Cs%2B%27%5B%5E%27%5C%5C%5D*(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%5B%5E%27%5C%5C%5D*)*%27)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as regex you can use:

```
/apiEndpoint:'https?:\/\/\w+(:[0-9]*)?(\.\w+)?'/gm
```

to insert the text you can use:

```
e.g. baseUrl = 'https://localhost:6000'

`${baseUrl}`
```

Note:
You can check your regex here: https://regex101.com/

e.g.:

[image]